# Infinitesimal generator of a Markov process

Tags: operator-theory, markov-chains, differential-operators

We define the *infinitesimal generator* of a Markov process as

$$Gf = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{K_hf - f}{h}$$

where $f$ is a function on the state space, $K_h$ is a continuous time operator on the Markov process, i.e

$$K_hf(x) = \int P_h (y \mid x) f(y) dy = E_x(X^{(h)})$$

where $P_h$ is the transition probability for time $h$, and $E_x$ denotes we start from state $x$.

Can you give an intuitive explanation of the infinitesimal generator? What does it mean? What role does it play in Markov process? How would you generate a Markov process using the so-called generator?

Answer (score 4):

In some sense, the Infinitesimal Generator of a Markov Process is *the* intuitive object. I will use a slightly different notation and use more common variable names.

There are many different approaches to Markov processes on some state space $E$. The first definition, one might encounter is the view as a family of probability measures $(\mathbb{P}_x)_{x\in E}$, where $\mathbb P_x$ is the law of the process started in $x$. Another point of view is via *semigroups*, that is the one you are referring to in your question. Here, for any bounded continuous function $f:E\rightarrow\mathbb R$, we define the quantity
$$
T_t f(x) := \mathbb E_x[ f(X_t) ],
$$
so that $T_t: C_b(E)\rightarrow B(E)$ is an operator that maps continuous bounded functions to bounded measurable functions. Even better, the family $(T_t)_{t\geq 0}$ is a semigroup in the sense that $T_{t+s} = T_tT_s$ by the Markov property.

The main problem with these two approaches is that is it not clear at all how to interpret these objects in application. Take the following example: I want to consider a Markov process on $\mathbb R$ that has a deterministic drift of $b$ units per time and jumps at rate 10 as follows: with probability $\frac{1}{3}$ it jumps up by 3, otherwise down by 1. Can you give me the family $(\mathbb P_x)_{x\in\mathbb R}$ of probability measures or the semigroup $(T_t)_{t\geq 0}$? The difficulty in this question lies in the fact that we describe the *dynamics*, but we want to have the complete object. This is similar to the difficulty of integrating. If I give you the derivative (the dynamic description), can you give me the corresponding function?

The first question is to understand, how we can formulate the dynamics mathematically. And we will actually take the idea of derivative a bit further. What we are interested in is to understand what $X_t$ does over a short time interval. So somehow, we would like to take the derivative of $X$. But that is not possible! Remember that even the Brownian Motion is nowhere differentiable with probability 1! Instead, we will take the ``derivative of the law". More precisely, we know that the law of $X_t$ is determined by the values $\mathbb E_x[ f(X_t) ]$, which is exactly $T_tf(x)$! In other words, we are interested in
$$
A_tf(x) := \lim_{h\downarrow 0} \dfrac{\mathbb E[ f(X_{t+h}) - f(X_t) | X_t=x]}{h}.
$$
In words: knowing that we are at $X_t = x$, how does the Markov evolution effect the value of $f(X_t)$ in an infinitesimal time interval? In the setting of *time-homogeneous* Markov processes, this simplifies to a time independent value
$$
Af(x) := \lim_{h\downarrow 0} \dfrac{\mathbb E_x[ f(X_{h}) - f(x)]}{h} = \lim_{h\downarrow 0} \dfrac{ T_hf(x) - f(x)}{h}.
$$
We call this object the *infinitesimal generator*. Note that $A$ is not necessarily defined on $C_b(E)$, but only a subset $D(A)$ which is called the *domain* of $A$.

In the example that I gave above, the infinitesimal generator is given by
$$
Af(x) := bf'(x) + 10\Big[ \dfrac{1}{3} f(x + 3) + \dfrac{2}{3} f(x-1) - f(x)\Big],
$$
defined for all bounded, continuously differentiable functions with bounded derivative $f:\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R$.

As you can see, I was immediately able to write down how the infinitesimal generator looks. And that shows the importance of the infinitesimal generator (and the reason why I consider it to be the more intuitive object!). The general way to construct an infinitesimal generator is to add up the different effects. Jumps from $x$ to $y$ are included in the form $f(y) - f(x)$, the multiplicative factor in front gives the total rate of this type of jump. For the drift and the diffusion part, it is equally simple to write down the generator. Altogether, that justifies why, from a modelling point of view, the infinitesimal generator is crucial, as it allows to build new Markov Processes by specifying their behaviours.

$\qquad$

Now comes your last question, and this one is probably the hardest one. Given an operator $A:D(A)\rightarrow B(E)$, is it possible to know whether there is a Markov process associated to it? Is this Markov process unique?

In general, the answer is **no**. However, this is actually a very well-studied problem for the reasons mentioned before. If you want to go down the rabbit hole, you simply have to google *martingale problem*. The most complete account is probably given in the book ``Markov Processes: Characterization and Convergence" by Ethier and Kurtz, although it is not the easiest one to read. I will try to give the general idea behind this concept.

First, note that one can easily show that, if $X$ is Markov with infinitesimal generator $A$, then for any $f\in D(A)$,
$$
M_t^f := f(X_t) - f(X_0) - \int_0^t Af(X_s)\;ds
$$
is a (mean-zero) martingale. [It is even possible to write down the quadratic variation explicitly, although the computations become quite cumbersome...] The idea of the martingale problem is to reverse this implication. Given an operator $A:D(A)\rightarrow B(E)$, can we find a process $X$ (and a filtration $\mathcal F := (\mathcal F_t)_t$ such that $M^f$ is a $\mathcal F$-martingale for every $f\in D(A)$? Is it unique? Is such a solution Markovian?

And then something magic happens: Whenever there is a unique solution to the martingale problem for any initial condition $x$, this solution necessarily is a *strong* Markov process! Also, existence holds under quite general assumptions. The main condition to check is that $A$ satisfies the so-called *positive maximum principle* which is analogous to saying that if $f$ has a global maximum at $x_0$, then $f'(x_0) = 0$ and $f''(x_0) \leq 0$. I will not be able to go into much details, but this analogy also stems from the fact that we view $A$ as something like a first (or second) derivative. The uniqueness (on which hinges the Markovianity) is often much harder to verify. But there has been a lot of theory to ensure uniqueness, for example via duality.